# How to declare char array[] using integers?

Tags: shift-register

Can anyone please tell me how to declare a char variable using a few integers?

I need to declare a byte information for `shiftOut()` function as char.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 0;
int d = 1;
int e = 1;
int f = 0;
int e = 0;
int f = 1;

char information[] = {"B" + a + b + c + d + e + f};

void setup() {
  Serial.println(information);
}

void loop() {
  shiftOut(pin, pin, MSBFIRST, information);
}
```

In command `Serial.println(information);` I want to get back `B01011001`

Now the output I am getting `⸮⸮`

Of course the simpliest way to create that will be:

`char information[] = "B01011001";`

But I need to change the individual bits in `int bit =` variable.

Please note that substition `int bit =` with `char bit =` is unable for my code, using int of value of individual bits is necessarily. Because I am using my project with blynk, and there is function `a = param.asInt();` ,  `param.asChar();` does not exist.

How to do that?

Thank you for responses!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting something wrong about `shiftOut()`. It will transfer exactly 1 byte (or 1 `char`). It does not take an array as parameter. I guess you want to write the 8 bits, that you are defining with your `int`s, as one byte out. Defining at byte directly would look like this:

```
byte information = 0b00101100;
```

The `0b` tells the compiler, that the following number is encoded in binary. So you have one single byte, that contains all your information (all the bits). Then you can do

```
shiftOut(data_pin, clock_pin, MSBFIRST, information);
```

(Please note, that the data_pin and the clock pin need to be different).

If you want to print the `information` variable to Serial, showing the binary representation, you can use the corresponding parameter of the `print()` function.

```
Serial.print(information, BIN);
```

Will print the binary representation (zeros and ones as text) of the variable. So, to get "B1011001", you would do:

```
Serial.print("B");
Serial.println(information, BIN);
```

Note, that the `print()`/`println()` function will remove all leading zeros.

---

How to put the `information` byte with your `int`s? Each of them is either zero or one and represents one bit. So you can use the bitwise operators to put them together:

```
information = (a << 7) | (b << 6) | (c << 5) | (d << 4) | (e << 3) | (f << 2) | (g << 1) | h;
```

For each `int` only the first (Least significant) bit is important, since the others are always zero (because the int can be only one or zero). So we shift the `int` value to the left by the number of the corresponding bit minus 1 (so shifting `a` 7 places to the left to put its least significant bit to the most significant bit of `information`. We are doing that for all our `int` values. Then we put them all together into one byte by using the `|` (bitwise OR) operator.

**Note:** We don't know, where these `int`s are coming from. Even when stating, that you absolutely need those `int`s, you could organize them in an array instead of single variables. That would look like this:

```
int int_data[8] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
...
// in a function (like loop() or setup())
byte information = 0;
for(int i=0;i<8;i++) information |= int_data[7-i] << i;
```

It's up to you, if you want to do that.